# Género para "The TARDIS"

Tags: traducción, género, comparación-de-idiomas

En una pregunta ya contestada anteriormente, [Why do Spanish words have gender?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/why-do-spanish-words-have-gender), se decía que es muy subjetivo asignar un género a una palabra extranjera que se integra al español. Si en la lengua original la palabra es masculina, en español quizás mantenga ese género. Por eso mi pregunta puede tener una respuesta muy amplia: ¿Cuál sería el género adecuado para **[TARDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS)** y por qué?

Comment: En el caso de palabras con siglas, lo normal es usar el género de la palabra base.  Pero probablemente debido a que TARDIS se lexicalizó casi instantáneamente en inglés, nadie en el mundo hispanohablante habría sabido desabreviarlo para saber qué artículo usar y de todas formas decir «los TARDIS» (que sería lo muy correcto en este caso) para referir a un objeto solo suena fatal.

Comment: @guifa _los TARDIS_: Mis oídos están sangrando...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esto dice Wikipedia:

> "La TARDIS es el producto del avanzado conocimiento de los Señores del Tiempo"

Y antes dice:

> "Es una nave de ficción"

Es una **nave** y **máquina** del tiempo, ambas palabras son femeninas, por lo cual TARDIS tiene que estar en femenino también.

Comment: Imagino que también hay una larga historia de llamar a los barcos (sean barcos, naves, yates, etc) siempre de femenino.  Al menos, así lo hacemos en inglés y dado que la cultura marinera era su propia cosa (tal vez la primera cultura cosmopolita jaja), parece que lo haríais (o habríais hecho) en español

Comment: @guifa En español, los barcos se pueden llamar en masculino o femenino, según sea la palabra usada para designar el tipo de embarcación. Así, tenemos *la Pinta* (una carabela) o *la Invencible* (una goleta), pero *el San Juan Nepomuceno* (un navío de línea) o *el Temerario* (un destructor).

Comment: Además tiene la apariencia de **una** cabina de teléfono, no (no he visto nunca el show)?