# When to use 'muchos' and 'muchas'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I'm learning Spanish and I'm confused between when do I use 'muchos' and when to use 'muchas'

Please help

Muchas gracias

Comment: Can you indicate some cases where you faced difficulties in deciding which to use? Thing has to do with the gender of nouns: we say 'Much**a**s gracias' because 'gracia' es feminine, while we say 'Much**o**s abrazos' because 'abrazo' is masculine.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused at 'Flores' and 'animales' amongst one example

Comment: Would something like this help you? [Why do Spanish words have gender?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8311/1674). It would help to have some background of your level of knowledge of Spanish, as well as what your mother tongue is

Comment: Another one - 'Ellos ganaron muchos competencias' or 'ellos ganaron muchas competencias'

Comment: Hi, I am an Indian learning Spanish. Pretty basic level as such

Comment: @Ronnie As fedorqui explains in their comment, whether you use ‘muchas’ or ‘muchos’ depends on the gender of the noun you’re talking about. ‘Flores’ and ‘competencias’ are both feminine plural, therefore you’d use ‘muchas’. ‘Animales’ is masculine plural, therefore you’d use ‘muchos’.

Comment: just use "muches" if you are feminist enough